# What can I do if a repository / PPA does not have a release file?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, ppa, repository

When I try to run `sudo apt update`, I get the following errors for the gnome3 repository. What can I do to solve these error. Is there perhaps a way to revert all my repos back to default? I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                       
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                   
Hit:3 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                              
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                          
Hit:5 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                    
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/andch/staging-fprint/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                       
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                  
Ign:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                   
Ign:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/vala-team/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You could look at the existing question with the (almost) exact same title..

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party *Personal Package Archives* or sources, thus all security checks are on you to perform (*if you value your system*). Picking one of your sources from your paste opens to https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3 where it's pretty clear to see its *abandoned* & won't offer anything safe/secure/valuable for your system; why did you add it?

Comment: No. I already looked at that post before posting one myself. The other one deals with some other repo while my problem is with the gnome3 repo itself. If there's a way I can apply that solution to my problem then please guide me how to do it.

Comment: You're asking the same question, you just remove the source in whichever method is easiest for you.  Using software sources (if you're using a Desktop system), or inside your package tool (a number of options exist here), at terminal using a text editor (I'd use `vim` but any editor can be used here) etc...  or just *reverse* the steps you used to add that *ancient* source to your system.

Comment: I reversed thru my steps and removed the outdated source. Thank you so much @guiverc! It's been a long day and I tried to install an outdated software by just copying a bunch of commands and running them at once. Oversight on my part. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it solved, well done...   We all *get in a hurry & skip steps* now & again, thus creating a mess we need to clean up..  You're not alone !